# custom nested routes with Kohana 3

Tags: routes, kohana

I have a Articles model and a Category model, both with a `url_slug` variable (what I would like to show up in the url when looking for it. here is how I would like to have the URLs appear:

```
//list all of the articles
http://example.com/articles   

//list of all the articles in that category
http://example.com/articles/:category_slug 

//a single article.
http://example.com/articles/:category_slug/:article_slug
```

How should I set up the articles controller and/or the routes in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a route like this

```
Route::set('articles', '/articles(/<category_filter>(/<article_id>))', array(
    'controller' => 'Articles',
    'action' => '(index)'
))
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'Articles',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

In your controller, you can access the filters/ids with

```
$category   = Request::current()->param('category_filter');
$article_id = Request::current()->param('article_id');
```

And filter your output accordingly.